# What is the proper way to reference a user in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-replies

If I am commenting and want to reference another user, sometimes when I use `@[username]`, I get a clickable pop-up with their username, other times I do not.

Some Meta questions indicate that `@` isn't needed anymore.

Is there old / new / draft guidance on the "correct" way to reference a user in comments?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is

`@username` with at least 3 uniquely identifying characters following the `@`.

You can only ping (reference) **one** user different from the OP.
The OP themselves can only be pinged (for clarity) if no other user commented yet.

Answer (score 1):

To reference a user, you have to use *@username*

> *@* is needed.

Also note that the Post Owner will be notified about your comment even if you didn't mentioned them.

Who are all the persons you can mention

1. The previous commentor (the comment should be visible).
2. The editor
3. The close voter if they closed it with one vote that is Mods and Gold tag badge holders